# How to gets variable information of other scenes c# unity3d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a script that reads the variables of another script and stores them in itself, but I can´t get the data stored and I don't know how else to do it, please help.

Unity 2019.1

```
public class contenedor2 : MonoBehaviour
{
  public string elemento1;

  public void finalizado()
 {
    contenedor elementos = GetComponent<contenedor>();
    elemento1 = elementos.contenedor1;
 }
```

But the script does not read the variables
(
contenedor is a script associated with an element of another scene which contains the variables that I want to read)

Comment: I am using 2 gameobjects, the first is in a scene that starts first and the object has its code the instruction DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
and it has a variable with an information x that I want to read from the second scene

the second is in the second scene and what I want to do is read the data from the first script, but I do not know how I could do it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  If a scene is not loaded, then it effectively does not exist until it is loaded.

What you might try instead is putting the script with the data into a prefab that's used by all scenes that need it.  If it's script-only variables, you could also try a static class, but then you need to manage the initialization and shutdown yourself.

Comment: The scene is not loaded but the gameobject have this instruccion
DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

Comment: Okay, so that will keep the object alive if you've been to that scene previously, but if you've never loaded it, it still won't exist.

Comment: the scene that contains the object that always remains loaded is executed first that the scene where I have the problem always, to reach that scene it is necessary to load first the scene that contains the object that is not destroyed

Answer (score 0):

With your current code structure, Your contendor class can have the variable as static.

### Your contenedor class

```
public class contenedor : MonoBehaviour
{
 public static string elemento1;
}
```

### Your New contenedor2 class:

```
public class contenedor2 : MonoBehaviour
{
  public string elemento1;

  public void finalizado()
  {
    elemento1 = contenedor.elemento1;
  }
```

PS: Code can be improved, Let me know if it helps.

Comment: when I put public static string, the editor tells me that the variable can not be read from another script because of the level of protection, thanks for your help

Comment: Can you share your project through github? I may be able to help.

Comment: https://github.com/shadowdancer1557/Ruleta      
(I speak Spanish, so some parts of the code are in Spanish)

Comment: github repo contains 2 scripts only. I expected the whole unity project.

Comment: https://github.com/shadowdancer1557/unity-ruleta   
(It is the project excuse me, I'm new to this)

Comment: The problem starts in the folder 11 items that is within 11-20, there are 2 scenes 11-1 and 11-2 what I want with the scprit associated with the element called container, is that when the scene changes the data that has saved are read by the element called container 2 that is in scene 11-2